# VMWare memory usage issue

Tags: memory, vmware-workstation

I have VMWare Workstation 8 installed on my host OS and my host OS is configured with 32 GB of RAM.

[image]

3 VMs were created and all of them are set to use 4 GB RAM. These VMs are using Microsoft Windows 2008 R2.
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, from the Virtual Machine Settings pages of all the three VMs, I saw this warning.

[image]

What does this warning mean? Currently I started all of the 3 VMs. Theoretically, my Host machine should at least use 3X4=12 GB memory. However, that is not the case. Take a look at the task manager program running on the host.

[image]

What's the problem? Anyone can give some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a problem at all, it's just saying that IF you wish to reduce the VM's memory allocation you need to do that with the VMs powered off, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Chopper. Another question is why my host machine shows that just 7.13 GB memory was used? I open 3 VMs each with 4GB memory.

Comment: VMWare have lots of clever ways of saving you memory, firstly they don't allocate real memory until its actually needed, so if a VM is allocated 4GB but actually only ever uses 2GB then only 2GB is taken from real memory.

Comment: Page sharing and ballooning are the two big [memory reclamation techniques](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf) making it possible for several virtual machines to use less physical RAM than they have been allocated. In your scenario, page sharing is most likely what's going on.